# Is there any mention of Scott Howard's mother in the original Teen Wolf franchise?

Tags: teen-wolf-1985

**Teen Wolf** originally was a 1986 fantasy-comedy film about, well...a teen wolf. Scott Howard lives with his dad Harold and is a good, if socially awkward 16/17 year old student with nothing else remarkable about him... until, one night after a party, he finds out he has a family curse that turns him into a werewolf. Eventually learning to control his "wolf outs", Scott uses the enhanced physical attributes of his new form to become popular, with the whole town going "wolf crazy" for their new basketball star.

In the spin-off cartoon of 1987, some things have changed: Scott's family is bigger, he is no longer an only child, and the werewolf lineage isn't a curse, but a family secret which *few* people know about. This creates the tension of Scott having trying to be a normal teenager and fit in, while having to assure his dad, eccentric grandparents and precocious little sister don't slip up and reveal it either.

However, in both these versions... **nothing** is said about Harold's wife. Scott's mother. We don't know if she was a human when she married Harold, or another werewolf...we don't even know if she's dead or alive.

In the 2011 series loosely based on the franchise, Scott *McCall* isn't *born* a werewolf, but becomes one when bitten by a sociopathic Alpha, David Hale. The rest of the series details Scott learning to use his abilities, facing other supernatural evils and growing his pack while keeping it all secret. His father, a federal agent, and his mother, a nurse, eventually find out and try to support him. This is a considerably darker tone than the 1985 predecessors, but at least details are included about his parents.

So I wondered if *anything* in the **original** Teen Wolf franchise spoke of Scott Howard's mother at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original 1985 *Teen Wolf* film, Scott's mother is actually mentioned a few times.  Early on, Scott's father Harold reminds him of her previous encouragement.  (The [script is available here](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=12023), but it is apparently a transcription without character names.)

> Your mother always said you could do anything you wanted to.

More significantly, Harold later tells Scott about a problem he and Scott's mother had had with vice principal Thorne, when the three of them were in high school.

> As you know, I loved your mother since we were kids.  We were meant for each other.  But for some reason Rusty Thorne set his cap for her too.  No matter what we tried, he wouldn't go away.

Harold explains that he had to wolf out and scare Thorne off, and he brings this up to warn Scott about the dangers of using his wolf abilities, especially to scare others.

> After that he never bothered your mother or me.  But to this day, I don't know who was the most frightened that night.  Old Rusty Thorne... or me.  You gotta get a hold of it, son.

(In spite of this admonition, Harold later returns to scare Thorne again, on behalf of his son this time.)

These are all the mentions that Scott's mother gets in the original film, although I think I remember her getting mentioned occasionally in the cartoon as well.

Comment: "*Your mom used to steal chickens. Till I blew her head off with a shotgun"* (I suspect this is meant non-literally)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget Mick tells Scott he shot his mother's head off while she was stealing chickens. Pretty likely a lie, but a reference nonetheless

> "You don't scare me, freak. Underneath all that hair, you're still a dork, Scott. I've handled your kind before. Your mama used to steal chickens out of the backyard until I blew her head off with a shotgun."

Comment: https://hardtickettohomevideo.com/2014/06/19/ask-professor-popcorn-teen-wolf/ for some reasons why this is probably just a boast/barb, not truthful.

Comment: Nice memory, B! unfortunately, this was not a real reference to Scotts _actual_ mom, but Nick's snarky way of calling her a female dog. I was referring to Harold Howards wife; while "missing mom syndrome" is common in pop culture teen stories, especially those where the main character is gifted with special abilities (i.e., Scott's lycanthropy) **not a single word** was given to Mrs. Howard outside of the vice principal, Mr. Thorne, and Harold being rivals over her when they were younger. I was actually wondering if she was a wearwolf too.